# Как реализовать систему браков телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Уже третий день пытаюсь сделать рабочий отрывок кода, в котором реализована система браков, но никак нормально не получается. В чём моя ошибка?

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils import executor

API_TOKEN = 'YOUR_API_TOKEN'  # Укажите ваш токен

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

marriages = {}  # Словарь для хранения информации о браках

@dp.message_handler(commands=['брак'])
async def propose_marriage(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    marriages[chat_id] = {'proposal_from': user_id, 'proposed_to': None}
    
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Да", callback_data="marry_yes"))
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нет", callback_data="marry_no"))
    
    await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Вы предложены в брак. Принимаете?", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == 'marry_yes')
async def accept_marriage(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    chat_id = query.message.chat.id
    user_id = query.from_user.id
    
    if chat_id in marriages and marriages[chat_id]['proposed_to'] is None:
        marriages[chat_id]['proposed_to'] = user_id
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"Поздравляем! Вы вступили в брак.")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Извините, предложение уже принято.")

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == 'marry_no')
async def reject_marriage(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    chat_id = query.message.chat.id
    user_id = query.from_user.id
    
    if chat_id in marriages and marriages[chat_id]['proposed_to'] == user_id:
        del marriages[chat_id]
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Вы отказались от брака.")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Извините, предложение не для вас.")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['развод'])
async def divorce(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    
    if chat_id in marriages and marriages[chat_id]['proposal_from'] == user_id:
        del marriages[chat_id]
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Брак расторгнут.")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Вы не можете подать на развод.")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['мой_брак'])
async def my_marriage(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    
    if chat_id in marriages:
        proposal_from = marriages[chat_id]['proposal_from']
        proposed_to = marriages[chat_id]['proposed_to']
        
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"Предложение от: {proposal_from}\nПринято: {proposed_to}")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "У вас нет брака.")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['браки'])
async def list_marriages(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    
    if marriages:
        for key, value in marriages.items():
            proposal_from = value['proposal_from']
            proposed_to = value['proposed_to']
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"Брак между {proposal_from} и {proposed_to}")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "В группе нет браков.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Поясните, что не работает или работает не так, как ожидается

Comment: @CausonQ , когда ввожу команду, чтобы предложить брак, бот пишет текст и две кнопки или вообще ничего не пишет, но суть в том, что я сам могу принять этот брак, а я хочу, чтобы брак мог принимать только тот человек, которому было отправлено приглашение на принятие в брак. Так же хочу, чтобы команда развода, там тоже есть кнопки, хочу чтобы только тот человек, который подал на развод, мог нажимать сам, и больше никто другой. Если брак принят, то он вообще нигде не отображается, то есть бот не сохраняет информацию. Может можно сделать это всё с помощью БД? Помогите пожалуйста, нервы на исходе..)

Comment: Куда-то ж нужно записывать информацию, что бы она сохранялась. Пишите в БД. Вам нужно проверять id: кому предложено с тем, который нажимает кнопку. В хендлере, как я вижу, проверяется только наличие id в словаре (крайне сомнительное место хранения)

Comment: @CausonQ можете помочь с этим? просто больше половины кода писал ИИ и я многое не понимаю, пытался делать через БД (тоже с ИИ), но выдавало ошибку. Помогите написать, просто очень сильно нужно реализовать браки в таком виде.